# Wordpress exclude featured image

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wp-job manager and want to get fetch allgallery images per post ID. I'm getting it with:
`get_attached_media('image', $post->ID)` function but I want to exclude all featured images from the gallery because they are smaller than the rest pictures so I tried something like that:

```
$photos = array_unique( array_merge(get_attached_media('image'), the_post_thumbnail()) );
```

and:

```
$photos = array_diff( get_attached_media('image'), the_post_thumbnail());
```

But without success so can I apply something like filter to exclude images with smaller resolution?

Comment: Try `get_the_post_thumbnail` instead, use `array_diff`, and wrap the second parameter in `[]` because [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) needs arrays. However, since you are working with objects, I don't know if the two images will actually be found to the same object instance. If not, call `get_attached_media` and loop over it, comparing each item's ID with the result of `get_post_thumbnail_id` and build your final array.

Comment: I tried it but it's still can't exclude the_post_thumbnail(). May be the_post_thumbnail is returning another type object?
The default function which was used in prolisting template was:
$photos = prolisting_get_listing_gallery( get_the_ID() ); but it's can't fetch any picture.

Comment: [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) does not return anything, it just echos. Instead you want either [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) or [`get_post_thumbnail_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/)